# merge csv files in a directory with delimeter ";" with the same headers and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I would like to merge several csv files (delimeter ";") in a directory and output them into a single csv file with either another ";" delimeter or with a ",". All csv files have the same amount of headers (the headers must stay) and they're called the same throughout all csv files. But their content might have duplicates which I want to have removed.

The files can have a size up to 20 MB.

The files start with the same name but vary at the end (in which a * replaces them)

```
import csv
import glob
import pandas


stock_files = sorted(glob(r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs\pc_dblatmonstat_*_*.log'))
print(stock_files)


files = [stock_files]
final_headers = [
        'Start Time', 
        'epoch', 
        'Host Name', 
        'Db Alias', 
        'Database', 
        'Db Host', 
        'Db Host IP',
        'IP Port',
        'Latency (us)'
]

merged_rows = set()
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'rb') as csv_in:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=';')
    headers = dict((h, i) for i, h in enumerate(csvreader.next()))
for row in csvreader:
        merged_rows.add(tuple(row[headers[x]] for x in final_headers))
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerows(merged_rows)
```

But I'm getting an error

```
 Line6: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'module' object is not callable
```

Can I please get an advice whether or not my code reflects my request and why I'm getting an error?

Comment: pandas read csv could help; however, a little more info about ur data. what column/columns have the duplicates which u want to remove? do u know those columns already?

Comment: change 2nd line to `from glob import glob`. but this will not be the last exception...

Comment: @sammywemmy I think the very same entries in each of the listed columns could appear more than once. I have to import the merged csv into a SQL table then, that's why I want to eliminate redundant entries.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Thanks. One step closer. Now I'm getting another error:
Line 25: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is me shooting in the dark; have a go at this and lemme know if it works

```
from glob import glob
import pandas


stock_files = sorted(glob(r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs\pc_dblatmonstat_*_*.log'))

final_headers = [
        'Start Time', 
        'epoch', 
        'Host Name', 
        'Db Alias', 
        'Database', 
        'Db Host', 
        'Db Host IP',
        'IP Port',
        'Latency (us)'
]

#read in files via list comprehension
content = [pd.read_csv(f,usecols = final_headers, sep='[;,]',engine='python') 
           for f in stock_files]


#combine files into one dataframe

combo = pd.concat(content,ignore_index = True)

#drop duplicates
combo = combo.drop_duplicates()

#write to csv:

combo.to_csv('new_file_name', index = False)
```

Comment: Amazing shot.
After changing the following, it worked like a charm!

`import pandas` to `import pandas as pd`

`sep=[;,]` to `sep=[;]`

`combo.to_csv('new_file_name', index = False)` to `combo.to_csv(r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs\output.csv', index = False)`